# Dell Poweredge R410 does not recognize second CPU

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell Poweredge R410 with two CPUs installed.

I tried everything but the second CPU does not get recognized by the BIOS or the Linux Operating System it has.

Both CPUs are Intel Xeon E5602 with these RAM configurations:

```
- CPU1 - 16GB ram (2 8GB DIMMs in slots 1 and 2)
- CPU2 - 4GB ram (2 2GB DIMMs in slots 1 and 2)
```

Couple of extra info:

1. RAM is working fine (I can get 20 GB of RAM if I use all CPU1 slots).
2. Both processors are also working fine. I can make work either one of them as the main CPU.
3. Both heat sinks are working fine.
4. No hardware failures when running Dell's hardware check.
5. If I use one 8GB DIMM on each CPU, it doesn't work either.

Is there anything else I need to setup? Manual doesn't say anything about a JUMPER and/or BIOS configuration needed in order to make both CPUs work.

One more thing: firmware, BIOS and everything are fully updated to their latest official versions.

Comment: The CPU LGA socket may be bad. Have you taken some time to inspect the pins on the motherboard socket?

Comment: I had. There was nothing wrong with the LGA socket to the naked eye.

Comment: Sounds like a bad socket.  Your RAM configurations seem suspect, and if the machine was recognizing the second CPU it should be squawking about the memory configuration, but given that it doesn't that supports the "dead socket" theory even more.